# How to retrieve json value and store in variable angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have JSON like this, please see the below

```
{
  "Semester": [
    {
      "queueName": "Science",
      "totalCount": 300,
      "unassignedCount": 10,
      "subjectDetails": [
        {
          "subjectName": "Chemistry",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "onTrackTradeCount": 150
        },
        {
          "subjectName": "Biology",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "sectionThree": 150
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "queueName": "Arts",
      "totalCount": 300,
      "unassignedCount": 10,
      "subjectDetails": [
        {
          "subjectName": "Indexing",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "sectionThree": 150
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "queueName": "Humanity",
      "totalCount": 300,
      "unassignedCount": 10,
      "subjectDetails": [
        {
          "subjectName": "Indexing",
          "sectionOne": 100,
          "sectionTwo": 50,
          "sectionThree": 150
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Semester values are displaying in multi select dropdown using matselect angular material. if some one select the paricular semester, the corresponding subjectName should display on another drop down.

I am not getting the way to do this, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong your requirement is to have a dropdown for semester items and then another dropdown for subjects based on the first dropdown.

In your *.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="Semester" [(value)]="choosenSub">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let sem of Semester" [value]="sem.subjectDetails">
   {{ sem.queueName }}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
 <br>
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="Subject">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let sub of choosenSub" [value]="sub.subjectName" >
   {{ sub.subjectName }}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your *.component.ts

```
choosenSub = '';
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1aagih)

Below is how it works:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, it second drop down values are not visible.  Also how it will work if I select more than one semster, please advice

Comment: you can see the second dropdown values as well, refer to the SS i attached and the stackblitz link for code.

Comment: I updated the [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1aagih) with another dropdown where you can select multiple items and store the selected values in an [ ]. For every selection i am logging the updated [ ]. You can use that [ ] for get the list of subjectNames and  then populate in the second dropdown

Comment: thank you for the help, its working almost good, but I am getting duplicate value on multi select, please advice how to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are going to need the to use something similar to the following for your template:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let sem of Semester" [value]="sem.queueName" formControlName="firstDropdown">
    {{ sem.queueName }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let sub of selectedSemester.subjectDetails">
    {{ sub.subjectName }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your corresponding typescript file you could then bind the two together such that `selectedSemester` is initialized to `Semester[0]` and updates whenever the first dropdown value is changed. Personally I would probably use a class-based form and then subscribe to the change observable and set the `selectedSemester` in the data callback. There may be a much better solution and I have not tested this, but it could look similar to the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedSemester = this.Semester[0]
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
    data => { 
       const temp = this.myForm.get('firstDropdown').value
       this.selectedSemester = this.Semester.find(
         el => el.queueName === temp
       )
     }
  )
```

Hopefully this helps somewhat, but the exact implementation will depend a lot on the rest of your app.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response, it will work for multi select ?  if I select more than one semester, how it will work?

Comment: also myform is not defined any where, please guide

Comment: @mjck If you want it to work for multiple select then you will need to change `selectedSemester` to be a list and modify the observable callback to set that variable to the array that you want the second dropdown to iterate over. This can be complex, but hopefully the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) on reactive forms can give you some of the background you need. `myForm` would need to be defined somewhere as type Angular `FormGroup`  that can be imported from `@angular/forms`.

Comment: @Danial thank you for the response, it will be very help full if you share me working example of this.

Answer (score 0):

So, in your component you'll maybe have something like this.

```
 public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    semester: new FormControl(''),
 });
```

This is one option, now you have to get the mat-select value. The semester.subjectDetails is an Array Object, so, you just have to populate the other dropdown.

```
 <mat-select formControlName="semester" required placeholder="Semester">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let semester of JsonSemester"
                        [value]="semester.subjectDetails">
              {{ semester.queueName}}
            </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

Comment: could you please share me the complete code, thanks in advance